# Does "up" act as a preposition in the following sentences?

Tags: prepositions, verbs, adverbs, phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

1. "Put up the banner."
2. "Make up your mind."

I get the impression that "up" functions as an adverb or phrasal verb in both.

Comment: In both examples "up" is a preposition. It's better to say that "put up" and "make up" are verbal idioms. The term 'phrasal verb' is misleading: it is not the whole expressions "put up" and "make up" that are verbs; it's just the words "put" and "make".

Comment: I would not call them prepositions, as they are followed by a noun clause that they do not govern. But I know I am not up to date with CGEL's treatment of prepositions.

Comment: @ColinFine I can't see a noun clause in either example.

Comment: Sorry @BillJ, I meant "noun phrase".

Comment: @ColinFine No problem. You're right that the NPs are not governed by "up" -- that's because "up" is intransitive since it is a one word phrase, i.e. a particle in a 'verb-particle-object' construction. That it’s a particle is evident from the fact that it can also be positioned after the object (cf. "Put the banner up").

Comment: cont ... The rationale for “up” being a prep is based on the fact that it uncontroversially occurs as a preposition when it has an NP as complement (cf. “it crawled up the wall”), and there's no basis for assigning it to different categories according as it takes an NP or a clause -- or no complement at all. In other words, it’s just a matter of varying complementation, which is commonplace in English.